# Is it possible - Charset for AMP pages not utf8?

Tags: google, amp

Can I use for my AMP pages for Google meta charset and page encoding NOT in utf8; but windows-1251 for example?

I can't find any info in the specification about it.

Comment: Why would you want to use a character set other than UTF-8 for AMP?

Comment: Because all my content is win1251, it is a big portal 20 y. old :)

Comment: UTF-8 _should_ support Cyrillic characters. I have not found any AMP documentation that suggests that you can use anything other than UTF-8. Could you possibly re-encode the text as the page is compiled?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use anything else than UTF-8 for the meta charset, as noted in the AMP HTML Specification:

> Required markup
>
> AMP HTML documents MUST
>
> ...
> contain a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag as the first child of their head tag

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec#chrs

Possible solutions to converting your content's encoding depend on the server technology you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the charset to anything you want:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

However, know that users using a different character set will see a lot of garbled characters in your pages. If your website is 20 years old I would say it is time for a facelift and a few tweaks. You can find online utf-8 encoders that will make it easy for you.